# O que exatamente faz o método PDOStatement::bindColumn()?

Tags: php

Esse método é para manipulação de banco de dados. Não estou entendendo exatamente o que ele faz na coluna / variável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve para atribuir o valor de uma coluna do seu Select à uma variável.

Note que na documentação há uma explicação bem detalhada a respeito, mas para entender você deve estar familiarizado as "passagens por referência".

Veja:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT nome, idade, cpf FROM fruit';
  try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Atribuição pela posição da coluna
    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $nome);
    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $idade);

    // atribuição pelo nome da coluna

    $stmt->bindColumn('cpf', $cpf);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
      $data = $nome . "\t" . $idade . "\t" . $cpf . "\n";
      print $data;
    }
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Todas as variáveis passadas para o segundo parâmetro de bindColumn, passam a ter o valor da coluna especificada anteriormente.

No caso, quando fazemos `bindColumn(1, $nome)`, a variável `$nome` é criada e passa apontar internamente para o valor dessa coluna, cada vez que o `while` é rodado.

Note que na terceira chamada de `bindColumn` no exemplo, usa-se o nome da coluna em que se deseja "amarrar" (referência ou ponteiro) o valor para uma variável.

Observe que o segundo argumento de `bindColumn` é uma referência, então a mesma tem os valores atribuídos de acordo com  a chamada de `fetch`.

```
public bool PDOStatement::bindColumn ( mixed $column , mixed &$param [, int $type [, int $maxlen [, mixed $driverdata ]]] )
```

Para você entender melhor, as funções que possuem esse sinal de `&` no argumento, requer uma variável, para que valores adicionais possam ser devolvidos, já que o `return` está retornado algo diferente.

Por exemplo é a função `fsockopen`, que retorna um `resource`. Nela, você pode passar dois parâmetros  por referência para saber qual é o erro ou o código do erro.

```
 resource fsockopen($host, $port, &$err_no, &$err_str);
```

Ou seja:

```
 $handle = fsockopen($host, 80, $err_no, $err_str);

 if ($handle === false) {
      throw new Exception($err_str);
 }
```